# SAS 9.4 Character functions - Why might one cell return unexpected results?

Tags: string, date, sas, substring, string-length

I am manipulating some string variables and certain cells are returning unexpected values with substring and length functions. These cells hold character-formatted dates, as I need to do a few manipulations before converting them to SAS dates, because of the nature of the Excel file they're coming from. Here is an example:

HAVE:
Obs _orig
1 4/3
2 12/16
3 1/13
4 6/2
5 3/10
6 5/4
7 10/14

WANT:
Obs _orig _length _sub_1_2
1 4/3 3 4/
2 12/16 5 12
3 1/13 4 1/
4 6/2 3 6/
5 3/10 4 3/
6 5/4 3 5/
7 10/14 5 10

I am using this code:

```
data want;
set have;
_strip=strip(_orig);
_sub_1_2=substr(_strip,1,2);
_length=length(_strip);
run;
```

This is what I get. The discrepancies are bolded.
Obs _orig _length _sub_1_2
**1 4/3 5**
2 12/16 5 12
3 1/13 4 1/
4 6/2 3 6/
5 3/10 4 3/
**6 5/4 5**
7 10/14 5 10

Both are cases where SAS calculates length=5 when length should = 3. In both cases, the value for the substring-derived variable is blank altogether. Results are the same if I use compress(), trim(), or trimn() in my code, rather than strip(). Thank you for any help you can provide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like maybe unprintable characters got in your data.  If you `PUT _orig $hex.;` to the log, what do you see?  Should be: 342F332020

```
152  data want;
153   length orig $5;
154   orig='4/3';
155   len=length(orig);
156   put orig= len=;
157   put orig hex.;
158  run;

orig=4/3 len=3
342F332020
```

To get rid of non-printable characters, you could try:

```
_strip=compress(orig,,'kw');
```

Comment: Perfect! The non-printable character was an in-cell line break added by the owner/user. To make the compress function you supplied work, I added an extra comma: _strip=compress(orig,,'kw'); Thank you again.

Comment: Glad it worked. Good catch on the two commas. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems pretty clear to me that your variables have leading spaces or other leading characters that look like spaces on the screen. So for OBS=6 the value of the string is more like `"  5/4"` which has a length of 5 and the first two characters both look like spaces.  If LENGTHN() of your new `_sub_1_2` variable is not 0 then it has some non-printing character there.  Perhaps something like 'A0'X which some webpages use as a non-breaking space or tab character ('09'x).

I suspect that you don't want the first two characters, but instead want the first word when using `/` as the delimiter. You can use the LEFT() or STRIP() function to remove the leading blanks.  Or COMPRESS() to remove other junk. So you might use COMPRESS() with the `k` and `d` modifiers to only keep the digits and slashes.

```
data want;
  set have;
  length first $5 ;
  first = scan(compress(_orig,'/','kd'),1,'/');
run;
```